# I deleted the site-packages python?

Tags: python

I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.
Previous when I key in

$ python version

The terminal shows 
python version 2.7.2

However, I accidentally deleted the Python.framework. And now when I key in

$ python version

The terminal shows

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Is it my site-packages python deleted? 
What should I do?

Comment: Can you restore python.framework?

Comment: Have a look at https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/installing_python_osx/

Comment: That's why you have backups.  Restore from them.

Comment: It's somewhat surprising to me that `python version` ever worked at all.  Is that something Mac-specific?  If you just type `python` does Python run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python version` is not the command you are looking for. Use `python --version` instead. `python version` would execute a file with the name `version` in your current working directory.

In the topic you say that you removed the site-packages directory. In your post you say that you removed the Python.framework. Please correct this in your post.

**Python.framework**

OSX has two directories of this. One is your main Python installation which sits in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and one sits in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. Only the second directory contains the site-packages directory because this one is more related to local users. Python seems to work on your machine so execute it in your terminal and call the following code to get the correct path:

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

**site-packages**

In the worst case you just deleted some third-party libraries which need to be reinstalled. In that case just reinstall the necessary third-party libraries you installed over the time.